# Why does Heroes show inconsistent versions of the same scene

Tags: heroes

I've noticed on Heroes that when they start off from a scene they showed on the previous episode that the scene is slightly different, like it's another shooting of the same scene, or maybe just a different cut.

For example, towards the end of season 1 episode 4, when Hiro appears to Peter on the train, Peter says: "How's this happening?" and Hiro responds with: "Sorry if I scared you; you look different without the scar", but when the same scene is shown at beginning of the next episode (season 1 episode 5), Peter says: "What?! Are you doing this?" and Hiro just responds with: "You look different without the scar". Why is that?

Comment: Could you give some examples maybe?

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroes had different writers and directors 'guesting' on each episode. Episode 4 was written by Tim Kring and Bryan Fuller and directed by Ernest Dickerson, whereas Episode 5 was written by Kring and Micheal Green and directed by Paul Shapiro.

Shapiro reshot his version of the scene in your example where future Hiro meets Peter for episode 5, [as producer Greg Beeman mentions the shooting of this scene in his blog for the episode](http://gregbeeman.blogspot.co.uk/2006/10/episode-5-hiros.html) - he also mentions the addition of guest directors from episode 4 onwards, and how they have a lot of control over thier idividual episodes.

I wouldn't be surprised if it followed that each writer/director got to reshoot their own version of those closing/opening scenes for each episode.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the series is about Alternate Realities: bad outcomes in one reality are 'prevented' by one of the characters travelling to an earlier point in 'The Timeline'  -several characters have Time Travel abilities- and taking steps to stop the 'bad future' happening; the second version of 'the future' shown is one where the protagonists have a better outcome.